# Need to locate a specific value from a dataframe based on a loc search

Tags: python, pandas, max, pandas-loc

I'm working with this dataframe. I need to find a specific index number and, based on the inspect_date, I need to find the most recent name. I tried using the following code, but it isn't working:

`last_name= df.loc[[50096379],['INSPECT_DATE','NAME']].max()['INSPECT_DATE']['NAME']`

By using the following, I get the most recent date, but I don't know how to then get the most recent name:

`last_name= df.loc[[50096379],['INSPECT_DATE','NAME']].max()['INSPECT_DATE']`

Comment: Please share all relevant code and data. See: [mcve]. It would also be good if you could explain what you’re trying to do a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run: `df.loc[50096379].sort_values('INSPECT_DATE').iloc[-1].NAME`

Description:

- `df.loc[...]` - retrieve all rows with this key.
- `sort_values(...)` - sort them by this column.
- `iloc[-1]` - get the last row.
- `NAME` - and from this row return the name.

Comment: THIS WORKED!! Thank you so much. Could you explain what the iloc there is doing specifically?

Comment: *iloc* retrieves a row with the given **position** (integer, starting from 0). But as in many other places in *Python*, a negative value means "counting from the end". So argument *-1* retrieves just the last row.

Comment: Thanks again! Was struggling for the longest time!